# Problems reading UTF-8 data in MySQL from Java using JDBC connector 5.1

Tags: java, jdbc, java-8

I am saving data from php and fetching data either using java(limited experience) or from php.

When I am saving hindi data, I am able to fetch from php but not from java

In java i am using below connection string

```
jdbc:mysql://ip:port/db?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

but in java i am not able to display hindi content.

**on view i even tried**

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
```

but of no use.

**Data stored in Db**
à¤†à¤ªà¤•à¥€ à¤°à¤¾à¤œà¤§à¤¾à¤¨à¥€ à¤¦à¥à¤¨à¤¿à¤¯à¤¾ à¤•à¥‡ à¤¦à¤¸ à¤¸à¤¬à¤¸à¥‡ à¤¤à¤¨à¤¾à¤µà¤—à¥à¤°à¤¸à¥à¤¤ à¤¶à¤¹à¤°à¥‹à¤‚ à¤®à¥‡à¤‚ à¤¸à¥‡ à¤à¤• à¤¹à¥ˆ, à¤¹à¥ˆ à¤¨ à¤¦à¥à¤– à¤•à¥€ à¤¬à¤¾à¤¤?
à¤†à¤ªà¤•à¥€ à¤°à¤¾à¤œà¤§à¤¾à¤¨à¥€ à¤¦à¥à¤¨à¤¿à¤¯à¤¾ à¤•à¥‡ à¤¦à¤¸ à¤¸à¤¬à¤¸à¥‡ à¤¤à¤¨à¤¾à¤µà¤—à¥à¤°à¤¸à¥à¤¤ à¤¶à¤¹à¤°à¥‹à¤‚ à¤®à¥‡à¤‚ à¤¸à¥‡ à¤à¤• à¤¹à¥ˆ, à¤¹à¥ˆ à¤¨ à¤¦à¥à¤– à¤•à¥€ à¤¬à¤¾à¤¤? à¤•à¥à¤°à¤¾à¤‡à¤®, à¤ªà¥à¤°à¤¦à¥‚à¤·à¤£, à¤œà¥€à¤µà¤¨à¤¶à¥ˆà¤²à¥€, à¤®à¤‚à¤¹à¤—à¤¾à¤ˆ à¤œà¥ˆà¤¸à¥€ à¤•à¤ˆ à¤µà¤œà¤¹à¥‡à¤‚ à¤¹à¥ˆà¤‚ à¤œà¥‹ à¤¦à¤¿à¤²à¥à¤²à¥€, à¤•à¤¾ à¤¨à¤¾à¤® à¤ªà¤¾à¤•à¤¿à¤¸à¥à¤¤à¤¾à¤¨ à¤•à¥€ à¤°à¤¾à¤œà¤§à¤¾à¤¨à¥€ à¤•à¤°à¤¾à¤šà¥€ à¤¸à¥‡ à¤‡à¤¸ à¤®à¤¾à¤®à¤²à¥‡ à¤®à¥‡à¤‚ à¤à¤• à¤¹à¥€ à¤ªà¤¾à¤¯à¤¦à¤¾à¤¨ à¤¨à¥€à¤šà¥‡ à¤¹à¥ˆ.

- same is showing java api

Comment: how are you passing the data from DB to the view?

Comment: @Oleg its not wokring,

Comment: @eugene using native query